# zend pagination and searching

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have added the pagination on my records and also have the search filter on my list of records.But the issue is that when i am in first page and search for something it works perfect,but as I am searching from other pages like (2,3,4 etc.),it fetches the results but as I am in page 2 it does not show the results on my listing view.
The issue that I found out is the url is not changing while searching.

example: I am in  this page url -> http://test.com/album/contact-list/2
and Now I make a search from this page , the url seems to be same .

here is the pagination code
        //Pagination

```
    $page = $this->params()->fromRoute('page', 1);
    $paginator = new \Application\Library\Ex\Paginator();
    $paginator->setPageUrl("/album/contact-list");
    $paginator->setCurrentPage($page);
    $paginator->setRows(5);
```

and at last return to view model

```
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setVariable('data', $data);
    $viewModel->setVariable('status', $status);
    $viewModel->setVariable('published_filter', $contact->published_filter);
    $viewModel->setVariable('paginator', $paginator);
    return $viewModel;
```

and in module.config

```
    'contactList' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/contact-list[/:page]',
                         'constraints' => array(
                            'page'     => '[0-9]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller'    => 'Contact',
                            'action'        => 'contactList',
                            'page'=>1
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

Comment: post your code first.

Comment: useless without soem code examples.

Comment: if I understand you, you should set the search form action with page = 1. by the way it seems to me that it is better to hold search phrase  in the get(route) parameter, and do not use POST.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you just have to reset your page Variable if a post was send.